# Question about sentence structure

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

Is the following sentence correct?

> "You don't need so righteous a man as to do that."

I'm mainly unsure about the "so .. as to" part, I don't think I understand it thoroughly.

Also, can I say 'righteous a man' instead of 'a righteous man'? Those kinds of things are not always interchangeable, right? I don't think, e.g., 'beautiful a woman' sounds natural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is mostly understandable but not quite grammatical. It should be rephrased in one of two general ways:

> 1. You don't need so righteous a man as that.
> 2. You don't need so righteous a man to do that.

The first version is making a comparison between a level of righteousness and a particular man, while the second version is comparing a level of righteousness with the needs of a particular task.

When you combine both (*a man as to do that*) it's unclear which of the two senses is actually meant.

If you want to maintain a *so . . . as* construction but use it in the second sense, you could rephrase it:

> You don't need a man so righteous as that in order to accomplish the task.
>   You don't need a man so righteous as that for the job.

Note that there is a subtle difference in meaning between those two, even though they are broadly the same. The first says that the task can be completed by somebody less righteous, while the second *can* additionally be inferred to say that somebody so righteous should not be used for the job.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `so|as [adjective] a [noun 1] as [noun 2]`

means "a noun1 which is  [adjective] to the same degree that noun2 is [adjective]".

In your example, you cannot compare "man" with "do that", as "do that" is not a valid comparand in the pattern. It is verb phrase not a noun-phrase.

> To get up onto the roof of the cabin, you don't need as tall a ladder as that one.

The pattern `so [adjective] a [noun]`

means "a noun which is [adjective] to the degree that it is [adjective]".

> I don't need so big a car.   A car smaller than it will suffice.